# Solve $2\cos(x)^2 - 5\sin(x) - 4 = 0$ on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, problem-solving

This is homework.

I got it down to either $\sin(x) = -2$ or $\sin(x) = -1/2$ but I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Well, $\sin x$ is always between $-1$ and $1$, so $\sin x = 2$ has no solutions. That addresses half of your problem. Do you know any angle $x$ whose sine is $1/2$ or $-1/2$? Can you graph the sine function to try to make a guess, and then check it?

Comment: How did you get to that point? Also $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$

Comment: @David Replacing $\cos(x)^2$ with $1 - \sin(x)^2$, simplifying, and using the quadratic formula

Comment: @JohnHughes Is there a way to derive it or do I have to memorize a bunch of table? If you are given $\sin(x) = k$ for known $k$ how do you solve $x$ in general?

Comment: $\sin(\pi/6) = 1/2$ it would seem

Comment: Do you know the unit circle? It's pretty memorization, though there are a few tricks.

Comment: I know of it but not really how to use it. If $\sin(x) = -1/2$ then opposite over hypotenuse equals $-1/2$ but how can a triangle side's length be negative?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the function has no roots on the given interval...it should have roots at $-\pi /6$ and $7\pi /6$, but nowhere inbetween

Comment: @David Is it true that $x = -\pi/6 + 2\pi n$ at least? And then I put that in the inequality?

Comment: There are roots at $-\pi/6 + 2\pi  k$ and $-5 \pi/6 + 2 \pi k$

Comment: Can anyone explain where all of this is coming from? I just want to solve the thing and understand what to do before I put my head through my desk @_@

Comment: To answer your question about "memorizing a table": yes. You really SHOULD memorize sin and cos of $0, \pi/6, \pi/4, \pi/3, \pi/2$ and $\pi$ if you're going to be doing much more math. Every practicing mathematician knows them. But once you know the values for $\pi/6$, and a few things like the sine and cosine addition rules,  you can work out the values for $\pi/3$. Or you can just remember the shape of the 30-60-90 and 45-45-90 triangles. But there's no "formula" ... which is why mathematicians made up a new name for these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\cos(x)^2 - 5\sin(x) - 4 = 0$ on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$

$2(1-\sin^2x)-5\sin x-4=0$

$2\sin^2x +5\sin x+2=0$

$(2\sin x+1)(\sin x+2)=0$

Then either $\sin x = -2$ which has no solutions since $|\sin x |\leq1$

or $\sin x = -\frac{1}{2}$

Now, let's consider the graph of $\sin x$:

[image]

So we have $ x = -\frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ - this is because $y=\sin x $ has period $2\pi$, which means $\sin(x+2k\pi) = \sin x$

Now also note the following property:

$\sin(\pi - x) = \sin \pi \cos x - \sin x \cos \pi = \sin x$

Therefore, $x = (\pi - -\frac{\pi}{6}) + 2k\pi = \frac{7\pi}{6} +2k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now since the interval we are required to give solutions in is $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$, the solutions are $x= \frac{11\pi}{6}$ or $x= \frac{7\pi}{6}$

Comment: Lovely and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify by first rewriting $cos^2(x)$ as $1-sin^2(x)$. This gives us:

$2sin^2(x)+5sin(x)+2=0$, after factoring out a negative and combining like terms.

This factors into:

$(2sin(x)+1)(sin(x)+2)=0$

Meaning that $sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ or $sin(x)=-2$ (Which we reject).

This gives the following solution set:

$x={-\frac{\pi}{6},-\frac{5\pi}{6}}$ for $-\pi<x<\pi$ or $x={\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}}$ for $0<x<2\pi$.

Comment: This isn't correct; $sin(x) = -2$, not $-1$

Comment: $sin(x)$ cannot equal -2, the range of $sin(x)$ is $-1<sin(x)<1$

Comment: What I mean is $(2\sin(x) + 1) ( \sin(x) + 2)  = 0$ not $(2\sin(x) + 1) ( \sin(x) + 1)  = 0$

Comment: Actually yes, this was a mistake, the roots are actually $x=-\frac{5\pi}{6}, -\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: Additionally, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ turns out to be a root as well, depending on what domain you work with.